# Wordpress custom link with my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, urls

I wrote a plugin that stored table `wp_example(id, title, content, desc)`. It doesn't use `post/page` type.

I want to add a link to the fontend, like `index.php?option=my_plugin&show=all`. If I use this link, it should call my function in the plugin, and show data table `wp_example`.

Is it possible?

When I use this link: `index.php?option=my_plugin&show=all`, my browser shows a `404` page.

Comment: Create a new page and put a shortcode on it. https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: This can be done... ...when the page loads, you have to write the code so that it takes the query parameters and does something with them... ...what have you written that parses through the query params?  Providing code would be super helpful.

Comment: i don't want use shortcode, i want create a private my page, and not use post type or page type. Wordpress only can use link when you create page,post. I can use my link ?